# How to create a running sum summary in R

Tags: r, dplyr, cumsum

I'd like to create a summary report from dataframe `df` where each row is the cumulative sum of column `A` based on columns `B` (where `C` is another id column). Below is the data and output:

```
set.seed(154)
df <- data.frame(B = append(append(rep(1,10),rep(2,10)),rep(3,10)),
                C = rep(1:10,3),
                A = sample(0:10,30,replace=T)) %>% arrange(B,C)
```

output:

[image]

What I wrote was

```
df %>% arrange(B) %>% group_by(B) %>%
  transmute(test =sum(cumsum(A))) %>% unique()
```

But it's just summing each column B and not the cumulative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be we neeed to get the `sum` of 'A' by 'B' and then get the cumulative sum

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(B) %>% 
  summarise(A = sum(A))  %>% 
  mutate(A = cumsum(A))
```

Comment: I just realized this doesnt work when you group by two dimensions but want the cumulative sum be based on one dimension

Comment: @Ana    IN that case, may be you need `df %>% group_by(B, C) %>% mutate(A = sum(A)) %>% ungroup %>% distinct %>% group_by(B) %>% mutate(A = cumsum(A))`

Comment: Thanks, super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the function `cumsum` after a `group_by(B)`, i.e.:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   group_by(B) %>% 
   mutate(A_cum_sum = cumsum(A))
```

Note that the `arrange(B)` is irrelevant because your data is grouped by B. From context I deduce that only `arrange(C)` is important and you already used it in the preparation of your `df` so it is not needed again.